# LINQ to XML: How to get to child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm new to LINQ to XML and appreciate assistance with getting to child nodes.

XML document:

```
    <schedule>
    <job>
    <name>nativeJobExample</name>
    <group>nativeJobExampleGroup</group>
    <description>Sample job for Quartz Server</description>
    <job-type>Quartz.Job.NativeJob, Quartz</job-type>
    <job-data-map>
      <entry>
        <key>command</key>
        <value>native_job_example.bat</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <key>consumeStreams</key>
        <value>true</value>
      </entry>
    </job-data-map>
  </job>
  <trigger>
    <simple>
      <name>nativeJobExampleSimpleTrigger</name>
      <group>nativeJobExampleSimpleTriggerGroup</group>
      <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
      <job-name>nativeJobExample</job-name>
      <job-group>nativeJobExampleGroup</job-group>
      <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
      <repeat-count>5</repeat-count>
      <repeat-interval>10000</repeat-interval>
    </simple>
  </trigger>
</schedule>
```

I'm able to get to nodes like this:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@pmPathFileName);
XElement root = document.Root;
root.Elements("job").Where(e => e.Element("name").Value.Equals("nativeJobExample")).
Select(e => e.Element("description")).Single().SetValue("wwww");
```

The XML document contains multiple pairs of jobs and triggers.

Two questions on how to update values:

1. How do I get to job-data-map|entry|key|value?
2. How do I get to trigger|simple|name|repeat-count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood in the **first** case you want to update  element of certain  matching it by . You can do this like this:

```
        string key = "consumeStreams";
        string newValue = "false";
        var val1 = (
                       from jdm in document.Root.
                                            Elements("job").
                                            Elements("job-data-map").
                                            Elements("entry")
                       where jdm.Element("key") != null && jdm.Element("key").Value == key
                       select jdm.Element("value")
                   ).Single();

        val1.SetValue(newValue);
```

As for the **second** case. I would rather use a more concise syntax of XPath since no matching is required (from XML structure I have an impression there can be only one  element).

```
        var repeatCountElement = root.XPathSelectElement("/schedule/job/job-data-map/entry/key");
        if (repeatCountElement != null)
            repeatCountElement.SetValue("10");
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Since there are multiple job/trigger pairs, I made a minor change to the code.

Comment: string key = "consumeStreams";
            string newValue = "true";
            var val1 = (
                           from jdm in document.Root.
                                                Elements("job").Where(e => e.Element("name").Value.Equals("nativeJobExample2"))......

Comment: string newValue2 = "2000";
          var val2 = (
                 from jdm2 in document.Root.
                                                Elements("trigger").
                                                Elements("simple").Where(e => e.Element("name").Value.Equals("nativeJobExampleSimpleTrigger2"))
                                                where jdm2.Element("repeat-count") != null
                                                select jdm2.Element("repeat-count")                                       ).Single();                                           val2.SetValue(newValue2);

Comment: Glad it helped you anyway. Enjoy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, simplest being using XPathSelectElements like this:

var key = root.XPathSelectElements("/schedule/job/job-data-map/entry/key");